# How do I represent an homegeneous list of ADT in Scala?

Tags: scala, data-structures, adt

I'd like to express a contract that models a homogeneous list containing an ADT.

Let's say I have an ADT

```
sealed trait Letter
case object A extends Letter
case object B extends Letter
```

If I declare a contract like

```
case class Letters(letters: List[Letter])
```

I can instantiate the class as

```
Letters(Set(A, A))
Letters(Set(B, B))
```

but also as

```
Letters(Set(A, B))
```

I'd like to make this last case illegal at compile time.

Comment: Is not possible to do that with vanilla **Scala**, what is the meta-problem that you want to solve?